# Android: How to change view in Fragment that receive data from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bluetooth, android-viewpager

I'm developing application that receive data from bluetooth device to fragment in viewpager.
my application's process it

1. MainActivity receive data from bluetooth device
2. MainActivity's static String value changed as a data from bluetooth device
3. fragment's progressbar in viewpager in MainActivity refresh data as a MainActivity's data(changed integer)
4. fragment's progressbar refresh data and view whenever MainActivity's data is Changed

   ```
   public class BalanceFragment extends Fragment{

   public static String data = "0";
   private String old = data;

   private ProgressBar progressBar;
   private TextView textView;
   private Handler handler;
   private MyThread myThread;

   public BalanceFragment() {

   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_balance, container, false);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
       try{
           myThread.stop();
       } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
       textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.balanceProgressText);
       myThread = new MyThread();
       myThread.run();
   }

   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       myThread.run();
   }

   class MyThread extends Thread{
       @Override
       public void run() {
           while(true) {
               try {
                   this.sleep(5000);
                   MainActivity.println("test", "test");
               } catch (Exception e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               if (old != data){
                   old = data;
                   progressBar.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(data));
                   textView.setText(data);
                   progressBar.invalidate();
                   textView.invalidate();
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

however.... when I launch this application, view is frozen......
I don't know reason why my app is frozen

Comment: You should not update views from a separate thread, this may be the reason for incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a interface to communicate with fragment, for example:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    interface DataCallback {

        void onData(String data);

    }

    DataCallback callback;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(savedInstanceState);

        SampleFragment fragment = SampleFragment.newInstance();
        callback = fragment.getCallback();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "tag").commit()

    }

    public static class SampleFragment extends Fragment implements DataCallback {

        public static SampleFragment newInstance() {

            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            SampleFragment fragment = new SampleFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public DataCallback getCallback() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public void onData(String data) {
            //Update UI with data
        }
    }

}
```

every time your activity receives a new data you should call:

```
callback.onData(variableValue)
```

and pass the new data.

Comment: Do I apply it to my case that one application has 5 Fragment class separated MainActivity, 1 customViewPagerAdapter, 1 MainActivity??..... Must I implement Fragment as a inner class??

Comment: If you uses case in more complicated you car use [link](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) to create a producer interface on your activity and all consumer inside the other fragments. Here en example [link](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/)